# calling method in another class in php

Tags: php, oop

I am new to php and trying to call a function in another class.

How do I call function1 and function2 in class xyz???

```
class abc {
private $lmn = "lmn";
private $say1;
private static $static;

private function __construct(){
   $say1 = print $this->lmn;

}

public static function1(){

$static = "YEAAHHHH";
}

public function function2(){

    return $this->say1;
}
```

file 2:

```
require 'abc.php';

class xyz {

/**
* $e = new xyz();
*
*/


$e = xyz:: function1();// error
$d = xyz:: function 2(); //error

}
```

Also under what circumstance I should use

```
$obj = new class(); 
$obj->functionname();
```

and

```
$obj = class::functionname();
```

Comment: You have a type also `$d = xyz:: function 2(); //error` should be `$d = xyz:: function2(); //error`

Comment: `function1()` and `function2()` are in the `abc` class, not `xyz`. `function2()` is also not declared as a static function.

Comment: yes, so how should a call static and non static functions in another class XYZ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 2 different types of methods here, static and non-static.

#### To call the static (`function1()`)

- You don't need to instantiate the class, as it's static.

```
class zyx {
    public function foo() {
          return abc::function1();
    }
}
```

#### To call the non-static (`function2()`)

- You **need** to instantiate the class, as it's not static.

```
class zyx {
    public function foo() {
          $abc = new abc();
          return $abc->function2();
    }
}
```

Comment: but $abc =new abc(); // in my example will it not invoke the private constructor..????

Answer (score 1):

Static functions can be called without instantiating your class...

```
$myClass::function1();
```

Non-static functions need to be instantiated first:

```
$myClass = new abc();
$myClass->function2();
```

So in your example:

```
require 'abc.php';

class xyz {

    public function CallFunc1()
    {
        abc::function1();
    }

    public function CallFunc2()
    {
       $myClass = new abc();
        $myClass->function2();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    require 'abc.php';

    class xyz {

       public function static(){
          return abc:: function1();// this is a static function
       }
       public function nonstatic(){
            $e = new abc();
            return $e->function2(); 
        }

     }
```

Answer (score 1):

You would call function1 like:

```
abc::function1();
```

It is a method in `abc` not `xyz`.

`function2()` you would only call if you had an instance of `abc` because it is an instance method and not a static method. I.e.

```
$abc = new abc();
$abc->function2();
```

Static functions are intended to be called on classes, instance methods (i.e. `function2()` are intended to be called on *instances* of classes. I would recommend reading http://php.net/manual/en/oop5.intro.php.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you can't have a space between function and 2():

```
$d = xyz::function2(); //correct
$d = xyz::function 2(); //very incorrect
```

I was going to have a second of all, but @hd beat me to it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have messed up with the code. I can share something with something that I found very helpful as an answer for your second question. Spend a bit time reading this. This is very basic, simple and well guided.

http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/object-oriented-php-for-beginners--net-12762